# C# Application setting variable not working

Tags: c#

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017, and I'm trying to store a list of string in the Application Settings.
I made a setting variable of type Collection.Specialized.StringCollection.
The problem is, that after I update the value of the variable, it won't be saved in the next time I run the program.
This is my update code:

```
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        int tbInd = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Name);
        String[] arr = new String[63];
        Properties.Settings.Default.memoryRow.CopyTo(arr, 0);
        arr[tbInd] = tb.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.memoryRow.Clear();
        Properties.Settings.Default.memoryRow.AddRange(arr);
    }
```

I hope you will understand, my English isn't very well.
Thanks

Comment: you need to serialize your data, save it to a file, and then load the file when the program starts up

Comment: @Kristian that's what `Properties.Settings` is for. The question is why changes to `Properties.Settings.Default` aren't saved

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 seems like you need to call ```Properties.Settings.Default.Save();```

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default` contains the *default* properties saved in the `app.config` folder. That file can't be modified by the application. You can [save per-user settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) by calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save`

Comment: @Kristian thanks, the Save() function solved the problem